# Why elseif instead of else if?

Tags: php, conditions

Few days ago I stopped on some PHP's developers quide (for contributors to particular project) and it stated, that `elseif` must be strictly used instead of `else if` -- without giving any reason, why?

Can someone clarify this? I don't see neither much difference nor any argument supporting this.

Info: *I believe, there are more languages, than just PHP, that this problem strikes, that's why I asked here, not on Stack Overflow. Feel free to migrate, if necessary.*

Comment: This is answered in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662412/are-elseif-and-else-if-completely-synonymous)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The behavior when using curly brackets is exactly the same.  However when not using curly brackets but colon instead, the following will *not* compile:

```
if($a > $b):
    echo $a." is greater than ".$b;
else if($a == $b): // Will not compile.
    echo "The above line causes a parse error.";
endif;
```

I assume that the reason for preferring `elseif` over `else if` is either to be able to switch to and from curly brackets without creating a compile error or, probably more likely, it is a stylistic choice and prefers that only `elseif` is used.

[According to the php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/it/control-structures.elseif.php):

> Nota: Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the
>   same when using curly brackets as in the above example. When using a
>   colon to define your if/elseif conditions, you must not separate else
>   if into two words, or PHP will fail with a parse error.

Answer (score 7):

Besides [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/241498/31260), in both PSR2.0 and PEAR coding standards the use of `elseif` instead of `else if` is specified so that all control keywords look like single words:

```
<?php 
if ($expr1) {
    // if body 
} elseif ($expr2) {
    // elseif body 
} else {
    // else body; 
}
```

> The keyword elseif SHOULD be used instead of else if so that all
>   control keywords look like single words

Source: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#51-if-elseif-else